# Develop Android App Using VB.Net?

Tags: android, vb.net, mobile-application

i just wanted to start learning to develop mobile applications.. 
is there a way to create an app using Visual Basic .Net ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checkout http://xamarin.com/. They use .NET technologies so you may be able to use VB. I know most of there stuff is in C# though. It's not free to release publicly but you can at least get a taste for it for free.

In the end, it's best to develop using the native technologies used by each platform. You're just closer to the intended system with fewer layers of abstraction. So for Android, that would be Java.

**EDIT**

Looks like VB.NET is only support in libraries not the main code which must be C# (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/portable_visual_basic_net/).

Comment: Thanks for that.. i'll try to look at that ^^,

Answer (score 5):

Actually it looks like you really can develop mobile apps using VB.NET and Visual Studio using Xamarin.Forms.  I have not yet tried it, but I'm very interested in doing so.  I still prefer VB when I can get away with it, and this article looks promising with example code.

https://blog.xamarin.com/mobile-apps-with-visual-basic-xamarin-forms/

However, if you REALLY want to develop Android and iOS apps in Visual Basic in a totally dedicated IDE for VB developers, look into the B4A (Basic4Android) and B4i (Basic4iOS) products.  I've been using B4A for years and it is outstanding.  You develop in VB and it builds out to true Java APK files for android and native files for iOS.  Nothing touches it, really.

https://www.b4x.com

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you find B4A or xamarin not meeting your needs then it is time to write a transpiler that will translate your VB.NET code to java and then further compile to APK